Is the cartier duality of a group scheme the Hom_{R-Mod}(-,R) or Hom_{R-Mod}(-,R)?
I'm reading and reassuming R. Pink "finite group schemes" lecture course notes (in particular sections 2, 3, 4, 5, 11, 12, 13, 14) as an assignment.
At section \s4 there's a definition of Cartier's dual and it's not specified if the dual is of R-algebras o Mods.
I'm a bit rusty, because I had to do a semester of non-algebra exams so I forgot a couple of things. The doubt came to me when at the end of the section Pink says that the Cartier's dual commutes with the sum. However, I'm not sure how to prove that:
Hom_{R-Alg}(AxA,R)
is isomorphic to:
Hom_{R-Alg}(A,R)xHom_{R-Alg}(A,R).
By the way, I'm an undergraduate so I'm not very good with schemes (I know the definition and that affine schemes are antiequivalent to Rings which should suffice for now).
P.S. I'm decent for my level in category theory, so I should understand that.

Is this helpful: @ https://people.math.ethz.ch/~pink/FiniteGroupSchemes.html

@Matteo As commented below your answer, you should look into formatting properly. Also!!! Reread your title carefully - it doesn't say what you want it to say.

The dual is the $R$-module dual. Taking morphisms of $R$-algebras does not produce another $R$-algebra. A good example to keep in mind here is that the Cartier dual of the constant group scheme $\mathbb{Z}/n$ is the $n^{th}$ roots of unity $\mu_n$; in terms of their rings of functions this says that the $R$-module dual of the ring of functions $R^{\mathbb{Z}/n}$, as a Hopf algebra, is the group algebra $R[\mathbb{Z}/n]$, which is the ring of functions on $\mu_n$.
So it's not hard to check that Cartier duality commutes with finite direct sums on the level of the underlying $R$-modules. However there is a little extra that needs to be checked here, namely that also the group scheme / Hopf algebra structure is preserved.

Yes, the Hom of algebras doesn't have the zero in most cases. Yes I did it with the modules hom.

If the dual is Hom_{R-Mod}(-,R) then the whole thing is trivial, if its Hom_{R-Alg}(-,R) then Hom_{R-Alg}(A,R)xHom_{R-Alg}(A,R) should be isomorphic to Hom_{R-Alg}(A tensor_R A,R) and I don't know.
Ps A is finite and flat so is locally free.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Thank you very much

@MatteoMunafò Now that you know how to format mathematics here, please apply what you've learned to your question and answer.
